# android-what will happen if I put two widgets on top of each other and then touch them?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

in `RelativeLayout` designing, the child that is defined earlier has a lower z parameter. so it's possible to put a `RelativeLayout` on top of another `RelativeLayout` by using this technique, for example. now, if I have been registered an `onTouchListener` for each of them and now touch the upper `RelativeLayout`, what will happen? only the upper widget senses the touching or both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget with the highest Z order, at the X/Y coordinate of the touch event, will receive that touch event.